# What does 'Modify profile to enable bash completion?' mean?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm trying to install google app engine.  The instructions said to use this command:

```
$ curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com/ | bash
```

Now, the installer is asking me this question:

> Modify profile to enable bash completion? (Y/n)?

What does that mean?

**Edit:**

I answered yes, then I was presented with this question:

> The Google Cloud SDK installer will now prompt you to update an rc 
>   file to bring the Google Cloud CLIs into your environment.
>
> Enter path to an rc file to update, or leave blank to use 
>   [/Users/7stud/.bash_profile]:  /Users/7stud/.bashrc
>
> Backing up [/Users/7stud/.bashrc] to [/Users/7stud/.bashrc.backup].
>   [/Users/7stud/.bashrc] has been updated. Start a new shell for the
>   changes to take effect.

The installer added the following to my `.bashrc` file (Mac OSX 10.6.8):

```
# The next line updates PATH for the Google Cloud SDK.
source '/Users/7stud/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc'

# The next line enables bash completion for gcloud.
source '/Users/7stud/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc'
```

The first script is this:

```
script_link="$( readlink "$BASH_SOURCE" )" || script_link="$BASH_SOURCE"
apparent_sdk_dir="${script_link%/*}"
if [ "$apparent_sdk_dir" == "$script_link" ]; then
  apparent_sdk_dir=.
fi
sdk_dir="$( command cd -P "$apparent_sdk_dir" && pwd -P )"
bin_path="$sdk_dir/bin"
export PATH=$bin_path:$PATH
```

And the next script is this:

```
_python_argcomplete() {
    local IFS=''
    COMPREPLY=( $(IFS="$IFS"                   COMP_LINE="$COMP_LINE"                   COMP_POINT="$COMP_POINT"                   _ARGCOMPLETE_COMP_WORDBREAKS="$COMP_WORDBREAKS"                   _ARGCOMPLETE=1                   "$1" 8>&1 9>&2 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null) )
    if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
        unset COMPREPLY
    fi
}
complete -o nospace -o default -F _python_argcomplete "gcloud"

_completer() {
    command=$1
    name=$2
    eval '[[ "$'"${name}"'_COMMANDS" ]] || '"${name}"'_COMMANDS="$('"${command}"')"'
    set -- $COMP_LINE
    shift
    while [[ $1 == -* ]]; do
          shift
    done
    [[ $2 ]] && return
    grep -q "${name}\s*$" <<< $COMP_LINE &&
        eval 'COMPREPLY=($'"${name}"'_COMMANDS)' &&
        return
    [[ "$COMP_LINE" == *" " ]] && return
    [[ $1 ]] &&
        eval 'COMPREPLY=($(echo "$'"${name}"'_COMMANDS" | grep ^'"$1"'))'
}

unset bq_COMMANDS
_bq_completer() {
    _completer "CLOUDSDK_COMPONENT_MANAGER_DISABLE_UPDATE_CHECK=1 bq help | grep '^[^ ][^ ]*  ' | sed 's/ .*//'" bq
}

unset gcutil_COMMANDS
_gcutil_completer() {
    _completer "CLOUDSDK_COMPONENT_MANAGER_DISABLE_UPDATE_CHECK=1 gcutil help | grep -v '^information' | grep '^[a-z]' | sed -e 's/ .*//' -e '/^$/d'" gcutil
}

complete -o default -F _bq_completer bq
complete -o nospace -F _python_argcomplete gsutil
complete -o default -F _gcutil_completer gcutil
```

Comment: the cloud SDK and GAE SDK are a little different. if you only want GAE then you can get it here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a little search and what I understand so far is that [Bash Completion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion.html) is bash support for commands auto-complete.

So what GAE seems to be asking for here is to allow that for its command line tools.

It seems [git has the same feature as well](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Basics-Tips-and-Tricks).

Comment: Thanks for taking a look.  Do you have any idea what 'profile' is?  In my opinion, an installer shouldn't ask you cryptic questions.

Comment: I think it means your .profile file or anywhere your linux profile data is saved. And yes that was very cryptic :)

Comment: I don't have a `.profile` file.  I went ahead and answered 'Yes', and then I checked my `.bash_profile` file--nothing new in there.   So, I looked in `.bashrc` and there were a couple of new lines.  I'll post them in my question.  Thanks.